# Form criando dois dados idênticos na DB e não listando na página devida

Tags: php, html

***Script* do Formulário (all_processo.php):**

```
<?php 
    require 'conexao.php';

    $conexao = conexao::getInstance();


    $acao  = (isset($_POST['acao'])) ? $_POST['acao'] : '';
    $proc_id    = (isset($_POST['proc_id'])) ? $_POST['proc_id'] : '';
    $numero     = (isset($_POST['numero'])) ? $_POST['numero'] : '';
    $assunto  = (isset($_POST['assunto'])) ? $_POST['assunto'] : '';
    $requerente           = (isset($_POST['requerente'])) ? $_POST['requerente'] : '';
    $status     = (isset($_POST['status'])) ? $_POST['status'] : '';

    $inf_id     = (isset($_POST['inf_id'])) ? $_POST['inf_id'] : '';
    $de_setor       = (isset($_POST['de_setor'])) ? $_POST['de_setor'] : '';
    $para_setor     = (isset($_POST['para_setor'])) ? $_POST['para_setor'] : '';
    $informe        = (isset($_POST['informe'])) ? $_POST['informe'] : '';
    $data       = (isset($_POST['data'])) ? $_POST['data'] : '';
    $informante     = (isset($_POST['informante'])) ? $_POST['informante'] : '';
    $processo_id        = (isset($_POST['processo_id'])) ? $_POST['processo_id'] : '';


    if ($acao == 'incluir'):



    $processos = "INSERT INTO processos(proc_id, numero, assunto, requerente, status)
        VALUES(:proc_id, :numero, :assunto, :requerente, :status)";


        $stm = $conexao->prepare($processos);
        $stm->bindValue(':proc_id', $proc_id);
        $stm->bindValue(':numero', $numero);            
        $stm->bindValue(':assunto', $assunto);
        $stm->bindValue(':requerente', $requerente);
        $stm->bindValue(':status', $status);
        $retorno = $stm->execute();

        if ($stm->execute()){

        $informes = "INSERT INTO informes(inf_id, de_setor, para_setor, informe, data, informante, processo_id)
        VALUES (:inf_id, :de_setor, :para_setor, :informe, :data, :informante, :processo_id)";

        $tsm = $conexao->prepare($informes);
        $tsm->bindValue(':inf_id', $inf_id);
        $tsm->bindValue(':de_setor', $de_setor);
        $tsm->bindValue(':para_setor', $para_setor);
        $tsm->bindValue(':informe', $informe);
        $tsm->bindValue(':data', $data);
        $tsm->bindValue(':informante', $informante);
        $tsm->bindValue(':processo_id', $processo_id);
        $lol = $tsm->execute();


        if ($lol):


            echo "<div class='center1' role='alert'>Processo inserido com sucesso, aguarde você está sendo redirecionado...</div> ";
            echo "<div class='loader'</div>";
        else:
            echo "<div class='center1' role='alert'>Erro ao inserir processo, aguarde!</div>";
            echo "<div class='loader'</div>";
        endif;

        echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='4;URL=listarprocessos.php'>";

        }
    endif;
```

***Script* de listagem (listarprocessos.php):**

```
<?php
require_once ('restrito.php')
    ?>
<?php
require 'conexao.php';

$termo = (isset($_GET['termo'])) ? $_GET['termo'] : '';

if (empty($termo)):

    $conexao = conexao::getInstance();
    $sql = 'SELECT numero, assunto, requerente, status, de_setor, para_setor, informe, data, informante, setor FROM informes, processos, setores
            WHERE processos.proc_id = informes.processo_id
            GROUP BY informes.inf_id ASC;';
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute();
    $clientes = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

else:

    $conexao = conexao::getInstance();
    $sql = 'SELECT numero, assunto, requerente, status, de_setor, para_setor, informe, data, informante, setor FROM informes, processos, setores WHERE assunto LIKE :assunto OR numero LIKE :numero OR requerente LIKE :requerente';
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindValue(':assunto', $termo.'%');
    $stm->bindValue(':numero', $termo.'%');
    $stm->bindValue(':requerente', $termo.'%');
    $stm->execute();
    $clientes = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    endif; 


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Listagem - Controle de Processos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/xdxd.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/haha.scss">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/xdxd.mas.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/haha.mas.scss">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tables.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="imagens/pref.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <legend><h1 class="w3-center">Listagem de Processos</h1></legend>

            <form action="" method="get" id='form-contato' class="form-horizontal col-md-10">

                <label class="col-md-2 w3-text-black control-label" for="termo">Pesquisar</label>
                <div class='col-md-7'>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="termo" name="termo" placeholder="Informe o número ou nome do Processo">  <button type="submit" class="w3-button w3-black w3-right w3-display-right xdxd">Pesquisar</button>
                </div><br></br>


             <p>  <a href='listarprocessos.php' class="w3-button w3-black xd">Ver Todos</a>  </p>
            <p> <a href='registrarprocesso.php' class="w3-button w3-gray xd">Registrar Processo</a> </p>
            <p> <a href='index.php' class="w3-button w3-black xd">Ir para o Site</a> </p>
            </form>


            <div class='clearfix'></div>

            <?php if(!empty($clientes)):?>
            <?php foreach($clientes as $cliente):?>

            <?php
            if (empty($termo)):
            ?>
                    <table style='width:100%'>
                    <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Número</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->numero?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Assunto</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->assunto?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Status</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->status?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class="w3-text-black">Requerente</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->requerente?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tr>

                <?php
                else:
                ?>
                <table style='width:100%'>
                    <tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Número</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->numero?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Assunto</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->assunto?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class="w3-text-black">Requerente</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->requerente?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Status</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->status?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Setor de</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->setor?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Para setor de</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->setor?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Informe de <?=$cliente->setor?></th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->informe?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Data</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->data?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Informante</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->informante?></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    endif;
                    ?>
                    <BR></BR>
                    <BR></BR>

                    <tbody>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                                </tbody>
                </table>

            <?php else: ?>

                <h3 class="text-center text-primary">Não existem processos registrados!</h3>
            <?php endif; ?>         
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quando você verifica `if($stm->execute())` o método de gravação é executado novamente. Você precisa fazer uma consulta para verificar se os dados foram realmente gravados e então usar na sua estrutura condicional ou armazenar um uma variável o resultado booleano da função execute.

Comment: coloquei a variável $retorno no if, salvou apenas um dado porém os $informes não foram inseridos. 
creio que ele não esteja lendo o $informes ou o $tsm

Comment: Execute a função apenas aqui : `if ($stm->execute()){`

Comment: porém assim ele grava duas vezes os dados do **processos**.

que negócio chato.